# TeKaMoLo oder "Kurz vor lang"?

Tags: sentence-structure

What are the Satz-Elemente in this sentence and what rule decides the word order?

> Bei gutem Wetter verlässt sie pünktlich um Viertel nach acht das Haus.

I had thought that "pünktlich" was a Modal-Angabe and therefore belonged after the Temporal-Angabe "um Viertel nach acht"

Comment: I don't know the which rules determine, I just can say that this example is fluent German. The option "Bei gutem Wetter verlässt sie um Viertel nach acht pünktlich das Haus" sounds right as well, just not common enough. Maybe it depends more on which sentence part the stressing is. And btw: i never heard of TeKaMoLo before, so maybe you can add this for context (like https://chatterbug.com/grammar/german/the-tekamolo-rule )

Comment: After searching on german.SE for Tekamolo I found this Q/A, maybe it helps you: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/why-does-geben-break-the-tekamolo-rule (it just supports my idea that tekamolo is far from an always right rule)

Comment: Since your question is in English with some German sprinkled in, I did not want to mess with it too much, but in German it is "Satzelement", "Modalangabe", "Temporalangabe". No hyphens. Compare "Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän".

Comment: My text book TELC "Grammatiktraining Deutsch für B2" uses the terms Temporal-Angabe etc. which is why I used them in my question.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Here *pünktlich um Viertel nach acht* is temporal. It means not at *8:18*, but exactly *8:15*. On the other hand *tekamolo* is not a strict rule. The sentence is correct (up to an umlaut).

Answer (score 0):

Prepositional phrases, such as *um acht*, can have premodifiers.

> **Kurz vor acht** klingelte das Telefon.
>
> **Genau um Mitternacht** wurde ihr Sohn geboren.
>
> **Erst am Abend** leert sich der Platz.
>
> **Schon nach wenigen Minuten** ist er außer Atem.

These phrases are units, i.e. single *Satz-Elemente*, as is shown by the fact that they can appear in first position.

As *pünktlich um Viertel nach acht* is a unit, *tekamolo* has not been violated.