# Die Positionen von Satzteilen innerhalb des Mittelfeld des Satzes

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich arbeite mit einem Grammatikbuch (Hueber, „Übungsgrammatik") um besser zu verstehen, wie sich die Satzteile innerhalb des Mittelfeld des Satzes ordnen, weil das ein Schwachpunkt für mich ist.  Meine Antworten (MA) auf die Aufgaben sind fast richtig, aber stimmen mit den Lösungen des Buches (LB) nicht völlig überein.

Zum Beispiel:

- MA: Bei gutem Wetter verlässt sie das Haus um viertel nach acht.
- LB: Bei gutem Wetter verlässt sie um Viertel nach acht das Haus./Um viertel nach acht verlässt sie bei gutem Wetter das Haus.
- MA: Normalerweise bei gutem Wetter fährt sie mit dem Fahrrad.
- LB: Bei gutem Wetter fährt sie normalerweise mit dem Fahrrad./Normalerweise fährt sie bei gutem Wetter mit dem Fahrrad.
- MA: Am Wochenende macht sie Wassergymnastik mit zwei Freundinnen in einem Kurbad.
- LB: In einem Kurbad macht sie am Wochenende mit zwei Freundinnen Wassergymnastik./Am Wochenende macht sie mit zwei Freundinnen in einem Kurbad Wassergymnastik.
- MA: Samstagabends sieht sie sich gerne die neuesten Filme in einem der großen Kinos in der Stadt an.
- LB: Samstagabends sieht sie sich gerne in einem der großen Kinos der Stadt die neuesten Filme an./In einem der großen Kinos der Stadt sieht sie sich samstagabends gerne die neuesten Filme an.

Ich weiß nicht, ob meine Sätze *auch* richtig sind, oder ob sie nur grammatisch richtig sind aber trotzdem nicht richtig "klingen", d.h., dass sie nicht so formuliert sind, wie ein Muttersprachler sie machen würde.

Letztendlich, für mich am wichtigsten ist, zu verstehen, was der Fehler ist, den ich begehe, wenn ich einen mache, und welcher "Regel" mir helfen würde, diesen Fehler künftig zu vermeiden.

EDIT: Es scheint, das [jemand anderes sich mit diesen selben Aufgaben beschäftigt hat](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/why-does-geben-break-the-tekamolo-rule), und dazu hat er Antworten bekommen. Von dem, was ich dort gelesen habe, scheint es, dass es wirklich wenige feste Regeln gibt (oder irre ich mich)? Trotzdem, wenn ihr irgendwelche Hinweise hättet, wäre ich euch dankbar.

Answer (score 2):

Die Wortreihenfolge im Deutschen ist relativ flexibel und Deine Antworten sind nicht falsch; sie setzen aber einen besonderen Akzent, der vielleicht nicht beabsichtigt ist. Die Antworten des Lehrbuches geben die "natürliche" Gliederung wieder bei der kein Satzteil besonders betont wird.

Die "natürliche" Reihenfolge ist meist zuerst temporale, dann kausale, dann modale und schließlich lokale adverbiale Bestimmungen. Diese Reihenfolge kann man ändern, um einen gewissen Aspekt zu betonen. Eine leichte Betonung liegt meinem Sprachgefühl nach eher auf dem letzt-genannten Aspekt sowie dem zuerst genannten.

Achte auch darauf, dass das Verb im allgemeinen der zweite Satzteil sein sollte (bei deinem zweiten Beispiel "Normalerweise bei gutem Wetter fährt sie mit dem Fahrrad" stellst Du es an dritte Stelle, sodass man da argumentieren könnte, dass hier die Reihenfolge falsch ist - verständlich ist es trotzdem).

Comment: Danke!  Ja, lange her habe ich in Bezug auf die Reihenfolge von Satzteilen "time, manner, place" gelernt -- dem "Te Ka Mo Lo" ähnlich.  Und ich habe versucht, das zu machen, z.B. mit "Samstagabends sieht sie sich gerne die neuesten Fllme in einem der großen Kinos in der Stadt an".  Samstagagbends = Temporal, In einem der großen Kinos = Location.  Und mit dem Beispiel, auf das du dich beziehst, im Moment,  in dem ich es schrieb, war ic mir dessen bewusst, dass das Verb in der falschen Stelle war, aber ich dachte, vielleicht könnte ich "normalerweise" bis "Wetter" als ein Teil betrachten.

Comment: Zumindest "Normalerweise bei gutem Wetter fährt sie mit dem Fahrrad" ist nicht richtig, weil das Verb nicht an 2. Stelle steht. Wenn man das will, dann müßte man die beiden Bedingungen ("normalerweise" und "bei gtuem Wetter") in ein gemeinsames Konstrukt überführen: "Normalerweise **und** bei gutem Wetter fährt sie [...]"

Comment: Der 2. Satz **ist** falsch. Verständlich ist auch "Nrmalerweiz bei gut Wetter sie fährt dem Fahrrad mit."

Answer (score 1):

Die meisten Sätze klingen mit dieser Grundordnung am neutralsten:

1. Thema (nur im Hauptsatz)
2. V2-Verb (nur im Hauptsatz)
3. Subjekt
4. Pronomen-Akkusativobjekt
5. Dativobjekt
6. Adverbial der Zeit
7. Adverbial des Grundes
8. Adverbial der Art und Weise
9. Adverbial des Ortes (nicht der Richtung!)
10. Nomen-Akkusativobjekt
11. Adverbial der Richtung
12. Präpositionalobjekt
13. übrige Verben des Prädikats

Es gibt einige Verben, die von diesem Schema abweichen, zum Beispiel unakkusativische Verben wie *gefallen*: diese haben das Subjekt an der Stelle des fehlenden Akkusativobjekts. Weiterhin gibt es noch an Nominalphrasen gebundene Adverbiale wie z.B *am See* in *Ich ziehe in **das Haus am See.***, für die diese Grundordnung prinzipiell nicht gilt.

Und natürlich kann man auch bewusst gegen diese Ordnung verstoßen. Das sorgt dann für Spannung im Satz und betont die Teile, die nicht an ihrem üblichen Platz stehen.

Comment: Nach so einer klaren Aussage hatte ich lange gesucht, für mich ein guter Ausgangspunkt, um da aus DaF-Lehrer-Perspektive 'Ordnung reinzukriegen'.